# How to Properly Transfer Data from a Model Class to a RecyclerAdapter Class Using an ArrayList (Data Retrieval from Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am attempting to load an undetermined number of viewHolders into a recyclerView with data retrieved from the Firebase Realtime Database. This is for a messaging component of my Android app. I am first iterating through a list of chat keys (see "Chat Keys" node below) stored in the database under the current user's userID. For each key, I access the specific associated chat (see "Chat Basics" node below). For testing purposes, I am only retrieving and setting one value type ("lastMessage"), however I intend to set multiple values per viewHolder after successful testing. I am unsure about how to correctly pass the data stored in my model class for each iteration to my onBindViewHolder in my adapter class for display in individual viewholders.

I have had success in retrieving "lastMessage" for each iteration in my fragment class, then passing a string to my adapter class for each iteration. The viewHolders did display the correct string values. Though I can do this successfully, I need to be able to pass an arrayList of data for each iteration, so that I am not limited to only passing a single value per key. Because the onBindViewHolder in the adapter class is position dependent, it is my understanding that I cannot simply pass an array list with simple strings, but should instead pass an instance (O.O.C -might not be the right word) of the model class in an arrayList to be further accessed in the adapter class.

One way or another, please help me load a set of values into an undetermined number of viewHolders for each Firebase Database chat key iteration based on the code provided below. Cheers.

**Model Class:**

```
public class MessagesList {

private String lastMessage;

//Default constructor
public MessagesList() {
}

public MessagesList(String lastMessage) {//String userName,, String profileImage) {

    //this.userName = userName;
    this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    //this.profileImage = profileImage;
}

public String getLastMessage() {
    return lastMessage;
}

public void setLastMessage(String lastMessage) {
    this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
}
```

}

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class TestRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private ArrayList<MessagesList> mList;

//Data is passed into the constructor
public TestRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessagesList> messagesList) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mList = messagesList;
}

//Inflates the row layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.standard_chat_list_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

//Binds the data to the TextView in each row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.chatListLastMessage.setText(mList.get(position).getLastMessage());
        
}

//Total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView chatListLastMessage;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        chatListLastMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatListLastMessage);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

}

**Relevant Fragment:**

```
public class MessagingFragment1 extends Fragment {

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;//, personalChatReference;

private RecyclerView directMessageRecycler;

private String currentUserID;

private TestRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

private ArrayList<MessagesList> list_of_groups = new ArrayList<>();

public MessagingFragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messaging1, container, false);

    currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    directMessageRecycler = rootView.findViewById(R.id.directMessageRecycler);

    //directMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    directMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    //get a reference to the join table mentioned above
    databaseReference.child("Chat Keys").child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String groupId = (snapshot.getKey());

                databaseReference.child("Chat Basics").child(groupId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshotInner) {

                        MessagesList messagesList = dataSnapshotInner.getValue(MessagesList.class);

                        list_of_groups.add(messagesList);

                        adapter = new TestRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), list_of_groups);
                        directMessageRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                        //adapter.setClickListener();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
return rootView;

}
```

**Database Structure (x2):**
[image: Chat Keys Database Node]

[image: Chat Basics Database Node]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just forgot to return the correct item count

```
 //Total number of rows
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}
```

and the result was a blank recyclerView. Despite the stupid reason for having posted this question, I will leave it as an example for others (like me) who've had difficulty finding a concise, full example of **how to retrieve data from Firebase Database using simple key identifiers in one node to find the core data in another node**.